# How to load any activity by default when Page loads?

Tags: php

Below is my Code where user after sucessfully login can enter into website, but then it shows empty with left and right sidebar
I want the dashboard activity to load by default as the user signed in. How can I do that.

Here it is an library managment system whre user can borrow , edit return books and all history is recorded.

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);  
    include("databaseConnection.php");
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    if($_REQUEST['activity'] == 'logout'){
        $username = null;
        $username ="";
        unset($username);
        
        $_SESSION['username'] = null;
        $_SESSION['username'] ="";
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        
        session_destroy();
    }

    if(empty($username)){
        header("location: ../Index.php");
    }


?>

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
      <!--CONTAINER AREA  SECTION-->
        <div class="containerHome">
        <!--HEAD  SECTION-->
          <div class="headSection">

            <?php include("headSection.php"); ?>

          </div>
        <!--HEAD  SECTION-->

          <div class="navSection">
                <div class="welcomeTitle">Welcome</div>
                <div class="tooltip">Contact Us
                    <span class="tooltiptext">
                        <b>Address:</b> Central Department Of Physics, Kirtipur<br>
                        <b>Phone:</b> 01-4331054

                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="logoutLink"><a href="home.php?activity=logout">Logout</a></div>
          </div>

        <!--LEFT BAR  SECTION-->
          <div class="leftSection">
            
            <?php include("leftSection.php");?>

          </div>
        <!--LEFT BAR  SECTION-->

        <!--CONTENT AREA  SECTION-->
        <div class="contentSection">
          
            <?php     
             // CODE FOR PERFORMMING ACTIVITY..

                        $activity = $_REQUEST['activity'];

                   if($activity) {

                        if(isset($_POST['activity'])) {
                          include("dashboard.php");
                         }

                        if($activity) {
                            if($activity == 'addMember'){
                                include("addMember.php");
                            }

                            if($activity == 'dashboard'){
                                include("dashboard.php");
                            }
                               
                            if($activity == 'issueBooks'){
                                include("issueBooks.php");
                            }
                              
                            if($activity == 'returnBooks'){
                                include("returnBooks.php");
                            }   

                            if($activity == 'updateBook'){

                                $uBookId = $_REQUEST['uBookId'];

                                $return = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT bookId From borrow Where bookId = '$uBookId'"));

                                if(empty($return)){
        
                                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT bookId,title,author,price,publisher From books Where bookId = '$uBookId'");
                                    $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

                                    ?>
                             

        </div>
        <!--CONTENT AREA  SECTION-->

        <!--RIGHT AREA  SECTION-->
          <div class="rightSection">
            
          <?php include("rightSection.php");?>

          </div>
        <!--RIGHT AREA  SECTION-->

        </div>
        <!--CONTAINER AREA  SECTION-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error you got? Your code looks ok. You may have wrong path of your included files.

Comment: @daremachine I'm not getting any error bu when user signs in and then a page opens with left and right side bar but only when Dashbaord button is clicked ..Dashboard appears. so I would LIke to know to start Dashboard button active as the page loads by default.

Answer (score 1):

Change code below

```
<?php     
  // CODE FOR PERFORMMING ACTIVITY..

  $activity = $_REQUEST['activity'];

  if(isset($activity) || empty($activity)) {
      include("dashboard.php");
  }
  else {
     if($activity == 'addMember'){
        include("addMember.php");
     .............your code............
```

My advice is **DO NOT USE $_REQUEST** use $_GET, $_POST instead.

Comment: nope it didn't work ..instead when I click on Dashboard...it repeated twice ...and now I have two dashboard one below another.

Comment: change $_GET for $_REQUEST my mistake.

Comment: ..$_GET also created same problem so instead I use $POST but nothing changess....I have  edited my code as per your suggestion..can you please check if I have to place code at same place or not.

Comment: You should have a closer look at daremachine's answer. In particular the first query with "|| empty ($activity)" and the "else" statement after that. daremachine only ADDITIONAL said that $_REQUEST should not be used. His answer is all you need...